# SignalR "Start must be called before data can be sent" when responding to a server request

Tags: c#, signalr

I have some SignalR client code that invokes a server method after a request from the server:

```
        var connection = new HubConnection(_hubAddress);
        var hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(HubName);
        connection.Start().Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
  ...

        hubProxy.On("Client_Method", (string callerId, string requestIdentifier) =>
        {
           if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
           {
              // error hapening on the invoke call here, despite 
              // the connection state being connected.  
              // Do I need to call Start here?
              hubProxy.Invoke("Proxy_Method_Callback", callerId, requestIdentifier);
           }
        });
```

But its throwing an exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Data cannot be sent because the connection
>   is in the disconnected state. Call start before sending any data.

But if the hubProxy is connected and open to receive the request, why is it erroring on the invoke?

Comment: update your question method signature one which hubproxy is calling

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan sorry I don't understand your comment

Comment: method you are invoking using hub-proxy instance

Answer (score 7):

I find really weird that you get an error invoking something inside `proxy.On()` handler, because that handler will execute from server side thus you are connected. Are you sure you get the error in that exact line and not anywhere else?

**Short explanation**:

SignalR does not handle disconnections. You need to handle them by yourself

**Long explanation**:

When your client loses connection, SignalR will try to reconnect for about 20 seconds. The state is `reconnecting`. After that period, it goes to `disconnected` state and won´t connect ever again.

To handle this situation you must listen to connection state changes, and reconnect yourself when state == disconnected. I found out it´s better to create a new hub connection when doing this, otherwise you may get a wide range of exceptions and weird behaviors.

If you invoke any method in disconnected state your app will crash, so I recommend using always try/catch at invoking.

Normally you will want to re-invoke failed calls once connection is re-established.

I wrote a [class helper](https://github.com/xleon/ReliableSignalRClient/blob/master/ReliableSignalR.Client/ReliableSignalRClient.cs) to handle all the mentioned logic. It´s well tested on ios/android devices.

Comment: thanks, you seem to be the first person to at least understand my problem

Comment: link is not valid anymore.

Comment: Here's a new, working link to the [class helper](https://github.com/xleon/ReliableSignalRClient/blob/master/ReliableSignalR.Client/ReliableSignalRClient.cs#L89).

Answer (score 2):

As the error quotes your
`connectionState` seems to be disconnected from the hub you are calling. On the client you should first call the Start- function of the hub connention.

So your client connects to the server.
Example:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://www.contoso.com/");
IHubProxy stockTickerHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("StockTickerHub");
stockTickerHubProxy.On<Stock>(
"UpdateStockPrice", stock =>
 Console.WriteLine("Stock update for {0} new price {1}", stock.Symbol, stock.Price)
);
await hubConnection.Start();
```

[SignalR Connection/Hubs-Guide](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#establishconnection)

Hope this helps

Best regards,

Georg

Comment: I do have the connection and hubproxy code, the error occurs on the invoke

Comment: This might help you out a bit... http://mobile.codeguru.com/columns/experts/how-to-push-data-from-server-to-client-using-signalr.htm

Answer (score 0):

may be the reason is Invoking Method signature is not matching the method 
the one which you are calling

```
hubProxy.Invoke("Proxy_Method_Callback", callerId, requestIdentifier);

HubProxy.Invoke Method (methodname, Object[])

method
Type: System.String
The method to be invoked.
args
```

Type: System.Object[]
The arguments for the method.

```
_
```

> hub.Invoke("Acknowledge","Say Hello to MainHub");
>
> private void Acknowldege(object state);

Comment: nope, my method signature is fine, everything works but after some time I lose my connection

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error. I was simply passing the wrong hubname into `CreateHubProxy`.